# Regarding parentheses and the end of sentence period, when the parentheses begin in 1 sentence but end after a second complete sentence?

Tags: prepositions, parentheses, periods

“Jim likes bananas (as well as apples. He also likes most vegetables).”

The finished sentence in the beginning of the parentheses, with 1 or more complete sentences after the partial sentence, all within the same parentheses. Where does the final period go - in or out of the closing parenthesis?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you really allowed to put 1½ sentences in parentheses? You could avoid the whole problem by using a semicolon after apples, and putting the period after the parentheses.

Comment: Yes, that's how I solve this problem -- converting period to semi-colon.  The other possibility goes like this: *Jim likes bananas.  As well as apples. And he also likes most vegetables*.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Peter and aparente001

Answer (score 1):

Any sentence with parenthetical information needs to be constructed in such a way that the optional information makes no difference to the main part of the sentence. In other words, if by removing the information the sentence becomes ungrammatical, then the sentence *is* ungrammatical and the parenthetical information has been misapplied.

For instance:

> ✔ Jim likes bananas <s>(as well as apples. He also likes most vegetables)</s>.
> → Jim likes bananas.
>
> ✘ Jim likes bananas <s>(as well as apples. He also likes most vegetables.)</s>
> → Jim likes bananas

---

This applies to syntax and semantics as well as to punctuation:

> ✔ Jim <s>(sometimes)</s> likes to eat <s>(ripe)</s> bananas.
> → Jim likes to eat bananas.
>
> ✘ Jim <s>(sometimes likes)</s> to <s>(eat ripe)</s> bananas.
> → Jim to bananas.

---

As for rules governing how information inside parentheses should be presented (partial sentences, mixed sentences, and so on), that's a matter of style.

Many style guides say that if you break the information into multiple sentences, the so-called first sentence should start with a lowercase letter. Some indicate that the final sentence not have a terminating period. In order for the main sentence to be correct, a period has to go outside the final parenthesis. Whether or not this results in using two terminating periods, one inside and the other outside, or just using one—outside—might be a grey area, *stylistically* speaking.

If it can be presented in a way that appears simpler, or avoids this confusion, it's probably better to do so. (As one comment under the question said, use a semicolon rather than a period in order to keep it all as a single phrase so that it doesn't look odd.) In the case of this particular sentence, I personally don't see a reason to use parentheses in the first place; however, I acknowledge their use may have been contrived simply for the sake of the question.

Regardless, as a matter of style, how the information inside parentheses is presented is subjective—or determined by the particular style guide being followed.